# Continuous of metric space

Tags: functions, continuity, metric-spaces

Definition : Let $(X, ρ), (Y, d)$ be metric spaces and $f: X \to Y$ some
function. We say that $f$ is continuous at $x_{0} \in X$ if for every sequence $(x_{n})$ in
$X$, from the fact that $\lim x_{n} = x_{0} $ it follows that $\lim f (x_{n}) = f (x_{0})$.
The function $f$ is continuous if it is continuous at every point $x_{0} \in X$

The Problem : Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $x_{0} \in X$. Show that the function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$  given by
$f(x) = d (x, x_{0})$ is continuous.

Any idea how to use the definition in the task because I have no idea how to start

Comment: In a metric space $(X, d)$, what does it mean, in terms of $d$, for $\lim x_n =x_0$ to be true?

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in X$ be an arbitrary point, let $\{y_n\}\subseteq X$ be an arbitrary sequence which converges to $y$. Using the definition of $f$ and the triangle inequality we have for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that $|f(y_n)-f(y)|=|d(y_n, x_0)-d(y,x_0)|\leq d(y_n,y)$. Since $\{y_n\}$ converges to $y$ we have that $d(y_n,y)$ converges to zero, so $|f(y_n)-f(y)|$ converges to zero, so $f(y_n) $ converges to $f(y)$. Because the sequence is an arbitrary, we have a continuity of $f$ at $y$. Since $y$ is an arbitrary we have a continuity of $f$ on $X$.